# How to check if square canvases are overlapping in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, intersection

I am creating a game where the yellow square has to get through all of the other squares to reach the top of the screen. I am having trouble testing if the squares overlap to reset the yellow square. I have tried implementing other methods found on this website but none seem to work, unless I am implementing them wrong.

Right now, in the method intersectRect(i), I am checking the edges of the squares to the edge of the player square.

Another bug I am having, which is not the most important but worth mentioning, is that when the yellow square reaches the top of the screen, the scores goes up by many values instead of just 1.

Thanks.

```
<html>

   <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600">   
</canvas>

<script>

    var canvas;
    var canvasContext;


    //square variables
    var squares = [];
    var squareX = [50, 0, 640, 400, 575, 300, 373];
    var squareY = [100, 150,200, 250, 300, 350, 400];
    var forward = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true];
    var interval = [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15];
    const SQUARE_SIZE = 50;

    //player variables
    var player;
    var playerX = 0;
    var playerY = 0;
    var intervalPlayer = 0;
    const PLAYER_SIZE = 50;

    var score = 0;



    window.onload = function(){

        canvas=document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
        canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

        function calcMousePos(evt){

            var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            var root = document.documentElement;
            var mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left - root.scrollLeft;
            var mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.top - root.scrollTop;
            return{
                x:mouseX,
                y:mouseY
            };
        }

        //get mouse movement
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt){

            var mousePos = calcMousePos(evt);

            playerX = mousePos.x;
            playerY = mousePos.y;

        });

        //update screen
        var framesPerSecond = 30;
        setInterval(function(){
              moveEverything();
              drawEverything();
        },1000/framesPerSecond);


    }

    //moves each square based on the interval
    function moveEverything(){

        for(var i = 0; i < squareX.length; i++){
             if(!forward[i]){
            forward[i] = false;
             if(interval[i] > 0){
                interval[i] *= -1;
            }

            if(squareX[i] < 0){
                forward[i] = true;    
            }
        }else if(forward[i]){
            if(interval[i] < 0){
                interval[i] *= -1;
            }

            if(squareX[i] > canvas.width - 50)
            {
                forward[i] = false;        
            }
        }else{
            console.log("Error ball " + i);    
        }

        }

    }

    //draws each square on the background canvas
    function drawEverything(){ 

        for(var i = 0; i < squareX.length; i++){
            squareX[i] += interval[i];
        }

        //background
        colorRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height, 'salmon');

        //score
        canvasContext.fillStyle = 'black';
        canvasContext.fillText(score, 10, 10);

        //red square
        squares[0] = colorRect(squareX[0],squareY[0],SQUARE_SIZE,SQUARE_SIZE, 'red');
        //blue square
        squares[1] = colorRect(squareX[1],squareY[1],SQUARE_SIZE,SQUARE_SIZE, 'blue');  
        //green square
        squares[2] = colorRect(squareX[2],squareY[2],SQUARE_SIZE,SQUARE_SIZE, 'green');
        //white square
        squares[3] = colorRect(squareX[3],squareY[3],SQUARE_SIZE,SQUARE_SIZE, 'white');
        //black square
        squares[4] = colorRect(squareX[4],squareY[4],SQUARE_SIZE,SQUARE_SIZE, 'black');
        //orange square
        squares[5] = colorRect(squareX[5],squareY[5],SQUARE_SIZE,SQUARE_SIZE, 'orange');
        //purple square
        squares[6] = colorRect(squareX[6],squareY[6],SQUARE_SIZE,SQUARE_SIZE, 'mediumPurple');

        //player
        player = colorRect(playerX,playerY,PLAYER_SIZE,PLAYER_SIZE,'yellow');

        checkContact();
        checkWin();


    }

    //functions to reate rects
    function colorRect(leftX, topY, width, height, drawColor){     
        canvasContext.fillStyle = drawColor;
        canvasContext.fillRect(leftX,topY,width,height);    
    }

    function colorCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, color){
         //draws ball
        canvasContext.fillStyle=color;
        canvasContext.beginPath();
        canvasContext.arc(centerX,centerY,radius,0,Math.PI * 2, true);
        canvasContext.fill();

    }

    //check for contact between the squares
    function checkContact(){

       for(var i = 0; i < squareX.length; i++){
            if(intersectRect(i))
            {
                console.log("Overlap");
                playerReset();
            }
            else
            {
               //none
            }

        } 

        //while(playerY < squareY[i] )


    }

    //check the borders of the squares for contact
    function intersectRect(i){
      return !(playerX > squareX[i] + 50 || 
               playerX + 50 < squareY[i] || 
               playerY > squareY[i] + 50 ||
               playerY + 50 < squareY[i]);
    }

    //check if yellow square is at top of square
    function checkWin(){

        window.setTimeout(function(){
            if(playerY < PLAYER_SIZE){

                playerReset();

                for(var i = 0; i < squareX.length; i++)
                {
                    interval[i] += score/2;
                } 
                score++;
            }  

        },1000);



    }

    //reset the player to original position
    function playerReset(){
        playerX = canvas.width/2;
        playerY = canvas.height - 50;    
    }


</script>
```

Thanks for fixing my main bugs. The only this I don't see working now is the pause methods created. Here is what my revised code looks like. The main reason this is a problem is that when it resets, it doesn't give the player the time to move the mouse back down, it just immediately goes to the mouse once it moves. Thanks.

```
<script>

    var canvas;
    var canvasContext;

    var gamePaused = false;


    //square variables
    var squares = [];
    var squareX = [50, 0, 640, 400, 575, 300, 373];
    var squareY = [100, 150,200, 250, 300, 350, 400];
    var forward = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true];
    var interval = [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15];
    const SQUARE_SIZE = 50;

    //player variables
    var player;
    var playerX = 0;
    var playerY = 0;
    var intervalPlayer = 0;
    const PLAYER_SIZE = 50;

    var score = 0;

    //pause game
    function unpause() { gamePaused = false } // un pause game
    function pauseFor(time = 1000){ // defaults to 1 second
        pauseGame = true;
        setTimeout(unpause,time);
    }


    window.onload = function(){

        canvas=document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
        canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

        function calcMousePos(evt){

            var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            var root = document.documentElement;
            var mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left - root.scrollLeft;
            var mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.top - root.scrollTop;
            return{
                x:mouseX,
                y:mouseY
            };
        }

        //get mouse movement
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt){

            var mousePos = calcMousePos(evt);

            playerX = mousePos.x;
            playerY = mousePos.y;

        });

        //update screen
        var framesPerSecond = 30;
        function mainLoop(){
            moveEverything();
            drawEverything();       
            requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop); // request the next frame
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);


    }

    //moves each square based on the interval
    function moveEverything(){

        for(var i = 0; i < squareX.length; i++){
             if(!forward[i]){
            forward[i] = false;
             if(interval[i] > 0){
                interval[i] *= -1;
            }

            if(squareX[i] < 0){
                forward[i] = true;    
            }
        }else if(forward[i]){
            if(interval[i] < 0){
                interval[i] *= -1;
            }

            if(squareX[i] > canvas.width - 50)
            {
                forward[i] = false;        
            }
        }else{
            console.log("Error ball " + i);    
        }

        }

    }

    //draws each square on the background canvas
    function drawEverything(){ 

        for(var i = 0; i < squareX.length; i++){
            squareX[i] += interval[i];
        }

        //background
        colorRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height, 'salmon');

        //score
        canvasContext.fillStyle = 'black';
        canvasContext.fillText(score, 10, 10);

        //red square
        squares[0] = colorRect(squareX[0],squareY[0],SQUARE_SIZE,SQUARE_SIZE, 'red');
        //blue square
        squares[1] = colorRect(squareX[1],squareY[1],SQUARE_SIZE,SQUARE_SIZE, 'blue');  
        //green square
        squares[2] = colorRect(squareX[2],squareY[2],SQUARE_SIZE,SQUARE_SIZE, 'green');
        //white square
        squares[3] = colorRect(squareX[3],squareY[3],SQUARE_SIZE,SQUARE_SIZE, 'white');
        //black square
        squares[4] = colorRect(squareX[4],squareY[4],SQUARE_SIZE,SQUARE_SIZE, 'black');
        //orange square
        squares[5] = colorRect(squareX[5],squareY[5],SQUARE_SIZE,SQUARE_SIZE, 'orange');
        //purple square
        squares[6] = colorRect(squareX[6],squareY[6],SQUARE_SIZE,SQUARE_SIZE, 'purple');

        //player
        player = colorRect(playerX,playerY,PLAYER_SIZE,PLAYER_SIZE,'yellow');

        if(! gamePaused ) { // if not pause
           // do everything that should not be done during paused game
           checkContact();
           checkWin();
        } else {
           // you may want to show that you are waiting from the next round
           canvasContext.fillStyle = "black";
           canvasContext.textAlign = "center";
           canvasContext.fillText("Get ready",canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 4);
        }


    }

    //functions to reate rects
    function colorRect(leftX, topY, width, height, drawColor){     
        canvasContext.fillStyle = drawColor;
        canvasContext.fillRect(leftX,topY,width,height);    
    }

    function colorCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, color){
         //draws ball
        canvasContext.fillStyle=color;
        canvasContext.beginPath();
        canvasContext.arc(centerX,centerY,radius,0,Math.PI * 2, true);
        canvasContext.fill();

    }

    //check for contact between the squares
    function checkContact(){
       for(var i = 0; i < squareX.length; i++){
            if(intersectRect(i)){                 
                resetPlayer();
                pauseFor(); // pause for default 1 second
                break; // this breaks out of the for loop
                       // no point checking for other hits 
                       // once you found one.
            }     
        } 
    }

    //check the borders of the squares for contact
    function intersectRect(i){
      return !(playerX > squareX[i] + 50 || 
               playerX + 50 < squareX[i] || 
               playerY > squareY[i] + 50 ||
               playerY + 50 < squareY[i]);
    }

    //check if yellow square is at top of square
    function checkWin(){
        if(playerY < PLAYER_SIZE){
            gamePaused = true;
            score += 1;
            resetPlayer(); // reset the player
            speedUpSquare(); // create a function that speeds up the squares
            pauseFor(); // pause for default 1 second
        }
     }


       function speedUpSquare(){
             for(var i = 0; i < squareX.length; i++)
             {
                interval[i] += score/2;
             } 
       }


    //reset the player to original position
    function resetPlayer(){
        playerX = canvas.width/2;
        playerY = canvas.height - 50;  
        pauseFor();
    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Score adding to many?

The problem with the win is that you call the function `checkWin` every 30th second and in that function you do nothing but schedule a check for win in one second. I would have to run it to see exactly what is happening but a better solution is to do the following

```
// create a global that pauses the game
// when this is true then you are waiting to start the next play
var gamePaused = false;  
function unpause() { gamePaused = false } // un pause game
function pauseFor(time = 1000){ // defaults to 1 second
    pauseGame = true;
    setTimeout(unpause,time);
}

function checkWin(){
    if(playerY < PLAYER_SIZE){
        gamePaused = true;
        score += 1;
        resetPlayer(); // reset the player
        speedUpSquare(); // create a function that speeds up the squares
        pauseFor(); // pause for default 1 second
    }
 }
```

#### The main loop

Your main loop is also a little problematic, It is much better to use `requestAnimationFrame`

```
    // where you had 
     setInterval(function(){ ...

    // replace that interval function with 
    // create a mainloop function
    function mainLoop(){
        moveEverything();
        drawEverything();       
        requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop); // request the next frame
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop); // this will start the me main loop
```

This will give you a better frame rate (60fps) so you will need to slow down the speed (`interval` the variable you used for speed)

#### Pausing the game

In the function `drawEverything` you need to make sure you do not check for win while waiting for the next round to start. As by the `gamePaused` flag

```
    if(! gamePaused ) { // if not pause
       // do everything that should not be done during paused game
       checkContact();
       checkWin();
    } else {
       // you may want to show that you are waiting from the next round
       ctx.fillStyle = "black";
       ctx.textAlign = "center";
       ctx.fillText("Get ready",c.width / 2, c.height / 4);
    }
```

The test for hitting the squares is good but for one typo

```
function intersectRect(i){
  return !(playerX > squareX[i] + 50 || 
           playerX + 50 < squareY[i] || 
           //...................^........ Should be squareX[i]
           playerY > squareY[i] + 50 ||
           playerY + 50 < squareY[i]);
}
```

With that fixed change the checkContact function

```
// modify the to pause the game on hit 
function checkContact(){
   for(var i = 0; i < squareX.length; i++){
        if(intersectRect(i)){                 
            playerReset();
            pauseFor(500); // pause for default 1/2 second
            break; // this breaks out of the for loop
                   // no point checking for other hits 
                   // once you found one.
        }     
    } 
}
```

Think that covers most of it.

#### Some tips

Odd bit of code

```
   // you do this ?? colorRect does not return anything so dont know why 
   // you do this. Same for the squares
   player = colorRect(playerX,playerY,PLAYER_SIZE,PLAYER_SIZE,'yellow');

   // would be better as
   colorRect(playerX,playerY,PLAYER_SIZE,PLAYER_SIZE,'yellow');
```

#### Use objects

Using objects will save you typing and make the game easier to manage.

You have the following which makes it hard to add, modify, access squares and is just messy

```
var squareX = [50, 0, 640, 400, 575, 300, 373];
var squareY = [100, 150,200, 250, 300, 350, 400];
var forward = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true];
var interval = [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15];
const SQUARE_SIZE = 50;
```

You can create a single object for each square and add them to an array

```
 var squares = [{
       x : 50,
       y : 100,
       forward : true,
       interval : 15,
       size : 50,
       color : "blue"
    },{
       x : 0,
       y : 150,
       forward : true,
       interval : 15,
       size : 50,
       color : "Green"
    },
    // and so on 
 ]
```

Or if you feel confident

```
const SQUARE_SPEED = 15 / 2; // frame rate now 60 so half speed
const SQUARE_SIZE = 50;
const squares = [];
// when you create a function with arguments you can set defaults with
// the equal eg function blah(data = 1). If I call blah() without the
// argument it will default to 1. If I call with the argumen blah(2) data
// will be set to the argument 2
const addSquare = (x,y,color,forward = true,interval = SQUARE_SPEED,size = SQUARE_SIZE) => {
    squares.push({  x, y, color, forward, interval, size, });
}
addSquare(50,  100, 'red');
addSquare(0,   150, 'blue');
addSquare(640, 200, 'green');
addSquare(400, 250, 'white');
addSquare(575, 300, 'black');
addSquare(300, 350, 'orange');
addSquare(373, 400, 'mediumPurple');
```

You can access a square via the array. For example testing for player hit

```
  function testForHit(){
      var i;
      for(i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){
           var s = squares[i]; // get a square from the array
           if( !(playerX > s.x + s.size ||   playerX + 50 < s.x || 
                 playerY > s.y + s.size || playerY + 50 < s.y){
                playerReset();
                pauseFor(500); 
                break; 
           }     
     } 
}
```

And to draw them

```
  function drawSquares(){
      var i;
      for(i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){
           var s = squares[i]; // get a square from the array
           colorRect(s.x,s.y,s.size,s.size,s.color);
       }
   }
```

You could even add the draw function to the square object `squares[i].draw()` but that is something for when you get the hang of basic objects.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! Sorry for the confusing code, I based my project off of a Pong tutorial I got for free on Udemy and it used these methods. Once again I appreciate the time and effort put into answering my question.

Comment: @MaxChapin if you are still using the arrays `var squareX = [...`and so on. Check the array `var interval = [15, 15,...` If you count the number  of items in that array you will find the problem.

Comment: Yes I checked that and noticed it right before you responded, thanks though. Weird how it doesn't give an error in the console.

Comment: @MaxChapin Yes one of the got ya's of Javascript the empty array item evaluates to undefined and when you do addition or any operators (+-/*%) on undefined you get `NaN` (Not a Number) which in javascript is a `Number` eg `console.log(typeof NaN) // >> number` so it does not throw an error but neither can it use `NaN` to render.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you mind checking out my the post again (I edited it), I had a question on your pause features.

Comment: @MaxChapin I never ran the game so I was not sure what was happening. You will have to add a test for pause everywhere you only want stuff happening when the game is unpaused. So for example in mouse move `if(! gamePaused){ playerX = mousePos.x;
            playerY = mousePos.y; }` will stop the mouse moving the player while paused